# Do veteran users get more weight in the close vote reasons?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, close-reasons

I cast the last close vote on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22225027). It had **two** *unclear what you're asking*, **one** *lack of information* and **one** *too broad*. I voted on *lack of info* and that's the reason that shows up in the *on-hold* message box.

More than once I noticed that the reason I'm voting is the one that shows up when the votes are split in this manner (2x2x1). IIRC, previously both double voted close reasons would show up in the box.

What's the logic behind this nowadays?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do veteran users get more weight in the close vote reasons?

No. It is the type of the last vote used. The vote that closed the question.